# Is the limit of a sequence of B-measurable functions itself B-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, statistics

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A}\right)$ be a measurable space and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$. Let $g,f_1,f_2, f_3,\dots$ be real-valued functions with domain $\Omega$ that are non-negative and measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose each $f_n$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$ and that $f_n\rightarrow g$ pointwise. Is $g$ measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$? If this is not generally the case, will it be so under stricter requirements e.g. that the space be $\sigma$-finite or finite relative to some measure?

P.S. The reason why i'm interested in this question is because i'm reading the article "Application of the Radon-Nykodim Theorem to the Theory of Sufficient Statistics" by Halmos and Savage ([link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-20/issue-2/Application-of-the-Radon-Nikodym-Theorem-to-the-Theory-of/10.1214/aoms/1177730032.full)), where a similar claim seems to be implied at the end of the proof of Lemma 12.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23775/limit-a-e-of-a-sequence-measurable-functions-is-measurable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rudin (Real and complex analysis), it is true. Because, you can show that the $\sup$, $\inf$, $\limsup$, $\liminf$ of a countable collection of functions is measurable. Limit is a special case of limsup or liminf since they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! If it is not clear, just forget $\mathcal{A}$ and consider the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B})$ . Every $f_n$ is measurable there so the pointwise limit $g$ will be since measurable functions are closed by pointwise convergence.