# Is the almost surely limit of measurable functions measurable in probability spaces?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose we have $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{F}_n$ a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable functions converging almost surely to some $X$, (I think it is unrelated, but I know that the sequence converges in $L^p$ for $p\in(1,\infty)$ as well).

My lecture notes argue that then $X$ must be $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable as it is the a.s. limit of $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable functions. I know for instance that this is false in general measure spaces unless we assume $\mathcal{F}$ is complete with respect to nullsets (i.e., contains all the subset of every set of probability zero).

> So I wonder if my notes are implicitly assuming this completeness or there is some additional fact in probability that guarantees that this is always true for probability spaces? I could use a counterexample in the latter case.

*Note:* This question is similar to other questions made before but not for the case of probability so I wonder if there is something else going on (e.g. [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23775/limit-a-e-of-a-sequence-measurable-functions-is-measurable)).

Comment: You do indeed need the completeness even in a probability space. For instance there is a sequence of measurable functions on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1)))$ whose limit is not measurable. An *explicit* example is rather messy to construct, but it is not that hard to build one from a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set by using the Cantor set.

Comment: Still what is true (and your book is probably doing this implicitly) is that there is a measurable $Y$ with $X_n \to Y$ almost everywhere. To see this, set $Y(\omega)=\lim_n X_n (\omega)$ if the limit exists and $Y(\omega)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @PhoemueX I fail to see why this $Y$ you are defining is not the same as the original $X$ to which the $X_n$ converge. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Because the original $X$ might not be measurable. But one can show (using that the limit of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ exists if and only if $\liminf x_n = \limsup x_n$) that the set $\Omega_0$ of all $\omega$ where $X_n (\omega)$ converges is measurable and so is $\omega \mapsto \lim_n X_n (\omega)$ when restricted to $\Omega_0$. Thus, $Y$ (as I defined it) is measurable. If you change to the completion (or if your measure space is complete), then of course $Y = X$ almost everywhere.